# How to draw UML diagrams passing parameters through super constructor

Tags: uml

I have a superclass called A and a subclass called B that inherits from A. The superclass's constructor looks like this:

```
A(String name, char displayChar, int hitPoints, Behaviour behaviour) 

{
 this.name = name;
 this.displayChar = displayChar;
 this.hitPoints = hitPoints
 addBehaviour(behaviour);
}
```

A has attributes of name, displayChar, hitPoints, behaviour and has a method that calls addBehaviour which adds the behaviour to the object.

The subclass, B's constructor looks like this:

```
B(String name) {super(name, char 'b', 10, new WalkBehaviour()); }
```

Now my question is, does subclass B have an attribute of WalkBehaviour?

How would the UML diagram look like for this scenario? I know B inherits from A and A has Behaviour but does B has WalkBehaviour in this case? Since B doesn't have an instance variable of type WalkBehaviour in its class but only passes WalkBehaviour through its superclass's constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does subclass B have an attribute of WalkBehaviour?

No. There is none declared. The superclass will do something with that new object but obviously it's hidden in the mist of its implementation.

Inheritance is nothing that involves multiple object creation. Your `B` instance is just a single one which does have attributes and operations *like* its super class.

[image]

Thus, in a SD, you will see only one life line for `B`:

[image]

As you can see the `B` instance will just issue a self-call to the super class's constructor.

Note: as @AxelScheithauer pointed out in the comment the super class will invoke `addBehavior` which can (but must not) be shown in the SD:

[image]

Comment: The class diagram captures the given information: B will not have an attribute of Type WalkBehavior. But – it will most likely inherit a private attribute of Type Behavior. At least that is the most common implementation of an add-operation. It will not be able to access it directly, because private attributes are only visible for direct instances of A. However, B can use it indirectly by calling operations of its superclass A (which have not been defined yet). An additional remark: The call to the super constructor will call addBehavior. Of course later the Actor could additionally call it.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer This all is hidden to us and pure speculation. You don't know what `A` is doing with the `Behavior` object. Moreover it depends on the compiler implementation (or basically on the compiler definition).

Comment: As I said „most likely“ and thus speculatively. What is not hidden to us is the fact that the super constructor calls addBehavior.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer True, this call could be shown in the SD (if intended). I might add this to the answer later.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Thank you for your elaborate answer. However, I have a question. When instantiating B, does B have a dependency to the WalkBehaviour class?

Comment: Yes, it has a Dependency. See my updated class diagram.